# How do I stop sublime text thrashing my hard drive on startup?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I have sublime text set to start on boot, with several projects open.

Every single time it immediately starts reindexing all of the projects and thrashing the hell out of my hard drive for 5 minutes.

The sounds my computer makes are not pleasant...

Is there a way to get sublime to persist its indices, or at least throttle its startup index?

Comment: Did you ever let indexing finish? You can exclude paths you don't need to be indexed, such as third-party dependencies (e.g. Node or Composer modules) or the build folder

Comment: Yes it finishes every time, and it still happens when I shut down sublime 'cleanly'. I could exclude things like dependencies, but I have them included precisely because I frequently need to look at their code, and that would only lessen the problem, not fix it